# Ways to ask about the time remaining before something is ready

Tags: sentence-choice

My friend is cooking food. I asked her if it's already ready and she said that it's not ready yet. Now I want to know how much time we have to wait until it'll be ready. What are the common ways to ask it?

Assuming my suggestions below are correct, are there more **common** choices?

> 1) How long it's going to take until it'll be ready?
>
> 2) How much time remain / left until it'll be ready?

Comment: The most ***common*** form is also the simplest: ***How long until/before it's ready**?* All your optional extra words are completely unnecessary, quite apart from the fact that you haven't got the syntax *quite* right in either of your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain please what's wrong with the syntax in my two examples and make me smarter?:)

Comment: *How long **is it** going to take until **it is** ready?* is more natural for the first. For the second, *How much time **remains / is left** until it **it is** ready?* is better. It's syntactically "valid" to use ***will be ready*** in the second (although perhaps not the *first*), but in practice if I heard ***will be*** in such contexts my first thought would be "non-native speaker making a logical but non-idiomatic translation from his native verb forms". Native Anglophones have a pretty strong preference for simple tenses (especially, ***present tense***).

Comment: Thank you.  I learnt something new today:)

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, @FumbleFingers highlighted some changes needed to your examples.

> - ❌ *No:*  1. How long {it's} going to take until {it'll} be ready?
> - ✔️ **Yes:** 1. How long **is it** going to take until **it is** ready?

Note that *it's -- "it is"* -- needs to be *inverted* to **"is it"**, because it's a question [(see more at this article)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/basic-grammar/question-forms).

> - ❌ *No:*  2. How much time *remain / left* until *it'll be* ready?
> - ✔️ **Yes:** 2. How much time **is left** until it **is** ready?
> - ✔️ **Yes:** 2. How much time **remains** until it **is** ready?

### More suggestions

You could replace "it" with *the food, lunch, or dinner.*

> - ✔️ **Yes:** 3. How long before *the food* is ready?
> - ✔️ **Yes:** 4. When can we eat?

To this they may say something like "in 15 minutes". This seems very informal to me.

> - ✔️ **Yes:** 5. When will the food be ready?

Again, seems very very informal.

> - ✔️ **Yes:** 6. I am starving. How much longer?
> - ✔️ **Yes:** 7. How long before we can eat?
> - Awkward: 8. How long before we can dine?

**Eat** is fine.  Notice that the verb *"dine"* isn't used this way in conversational English.

Comment: @whiskeychief Thanks very much for the wonderful edit and improvement. You are right about "dine" not being common in speech. When I was writing no. 8, I was imagining that I had been invited to my really pretty female friend's house for dinner. And the question with "dine" in it was asked with a flirtatious tone and purpose. I got carried away.